# How to Auto send SMS on a Particular Date and Time in iphone

Tags: iphone

Please provide me the code for sending sms on a particular Date and time in iphone.
Please suggest me the best way to do this.

I want to send sms after saving value in sqlite database like ph no. name, message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one is going to email you the answer, because then only you would benefit, and that's not the point of stackoverflow. You need to come back and check for answers here. I've removed the request for email from your question.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos: Actually he won't benefit either.

Comment: @BoltClock: He *mightn't* benefit. Then again, he might. It's a moot point, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has gone far and gave the programmers a way to present the end user with an SMS sheet (just like an e-mail sheet) , that they will have to approve (press send) in order to send SMS from a 3rd party app.

The reasons are mainly user privacy (as some apps on Android actually send SMSs on the user's behalf).

The best thing to do , in this case, is :

1. Create a local notification , that will remind the user that they need to send an SMS.
2. Upon launch (`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`) present the user with a prepared SMS sheet , so they'll just need to tap 'send'.

For more info , look at `MFMessageComposeViewController` class reference.